# Why does A2C use the actual returns from an episode in calculating the advantage?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, actor-critic-methods, bellman-equations

Why does A2C use the actual returns from an episode in calculating the advantage instead of using a bellman equation style estimate of the value?

Basically, why this:

$A(s,a) = \sum_t\gamma^tr_t - V(s)$

instead of

$A(s,a) = r + \gamma V(s') - V(s)$

This blog post seems to describe it one way, but their code is the other way:
https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-actor-critic-methods-931b97b6df3f

I feel there's some big gap in my understanding, but would appreciate some insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at how they derived the equation for that. Recall that $A(s,a) = Q(s,a) - V(s)$, so in the first equation, it is $Q(s,a) = \sum_t \gamma^tr_t$. We should noted that, the *original* Policy Gradient uses $A(s,a) = \sum_t \gamma^tr_t - b$, where $b$ is any baseline.

The first equation $A(s,a) = \sum_t \gamma^t r_t - b$, the original Policy Gradient, is *unbiased* because it is a single-sample estimate, but it has *high variance* because it sums all rewards, thus requires a good learning rate.

The second equation $A(s,a) = r + \gamma V(s') - V(s)$ has the advantage that it dramatically lowers the *variance* since it relies on all possibilities that can occur (Policy Gradient has the term "sum of the Advantage since step 0"). However, it is not *unbiased* because if the approximation of $V$ is incorrect, the policy gradient will fail to converge. Now this happens regularly with Neural Networks (NN) in Deep RL, because random initialization of NN already makes incorrect approximation of $V$.

In the end, what we want is an *unbiased* Advantage estimator, but needs to have *low variance* as well. We then use a critic as a the state-dependent baselines $V(s)$ for the Advantage calculation, that is the equation $A(s,a) =  \sum_t \gamma^t r_t - V(s)$ you see in A2C.

You can read more details in the [Spinning Up docs](https://spinningup.openai.com/en/latest/spinningup/rl_intro3.html#baselines-in-policy-gradients), [RAIL Lecture 6](http://rail.eecs.berkeley.edu/deeprlcourse-fa21/static/slides/lec-6.pdf), and [RAIL homework 2](http://rail.eecs.berkeley.edu/deeprlcourse-fa21/static/homeworks/hw2.pdf) if you want to know why they come up with such equation.

Comment: Another way to balance the bias-variance trade-off is to use the Generalized Advantage Estimation (https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.02438)